# Allowing a build target to fail in Waf

Tags: waf

How do I mark a rule in Waf such that the build doesn't stop on that rule's failure?

ex.

```
bld(rule="magicalcommand {SRC} {TGT}", source="somefile", target="othersuchfile")
```

where `magicalcommand` may somehow fail (but it's *okay* for that command to fail).

Comment: Not related to waf specifically, but to all build systems in general - you could create a wrapper script that will return 0 regardless of it's content commands results (or even `magicalcommand || true` for nix systems). Sadly it isn't too portable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by turning the rule from a string into a function with the actual execution call wrapped into a try/except block:

```
def somefunc(task):
    # set up the command string using task.inputs, task.outputs [, and task.env]
    cmd = 'magicalcommand ' + task.inputs[0].abspath() + ' ' + task.outputs[0].abspath()
    try:
        return bld.cmd_and_log(cmd)
    except Exception as e:
        from waflib import Logs
        Logs.info('cmd failed!')
        return 0

bld(rule=somefunc, source='somefile', target='othersuchfile')
```

Note that I'm using `bld.cmd_and_log`, not `bld.exec_command`. The former actually throws on error (and supposedly supplies access to the `stdout` and `stderr` of the command through `e` on failure), the latter just kills the entire build process for me.